# Unable to identify textbox as name and id are both dynamic

Tags: html, jsp, dynamic

I am working on a page developed using a complex JSP based UI framework (ie it is not simple HTML)
I am trying to access a textbox on this page via code, but I am unable to identify it.
Using Web developer I can see the following attributes of this textbox.

I cannot use name or id since both are dynamic and keep changing.

Also , I cannot change the UI code.

What can I do ?

Thanks in advance.

---

input #null1322135585319 .required

Attributes

```
type = text
maxlength = 70
size = 60
class = required
value =
name = components$loadWizardStep$OR:wt.pdmlink.PDMLinkProduct:15863$|changeNotice$create_details$OR:wt.pdmlink.PDMLinkProduct:15863$___MdlAttr+java.lang.String+WCTYPE|wt.change2.WTChangeOrder2|com.ECO~MBA|name~~NEW|2272329007416362203~+null_col_MdlAttr+java.lang.String+WCTYPE|wt.change2.WTChangeOrder2|com.ECO~MBA|name~~NEW|2272329007416362203~+null___textbox
id = null1322135585319
```

Comment: Hi Sandy , Thanks for your reply , but which code are you asking for ? I have already posted the source code that I can see via Web developer .

Comment: JSP alone cannot change an existing page without a refresh. It is generated by the server and comes to the client as static HTML. What you posted is not code; we are looking for HTML or JavaScript. If you have knowledge about the page you can use JavaScript to select elements by attribute values, tag names, or by how the tag is logically arranged on the page (i.e. what parent elements it has).